# wmic - don't work when runs from Task Scheulder (`No Instance(s) Available.` @ win10 )

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, mapped-drive

I'm writing a small check_mk plugin to check if monitor drives are mounted.

Everything works when I run the script from cmd but it won't when triggered from Task Scheduler.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


set "filename=C:\Users\abba\cifs.txt"

echo ^<^<^<cifsmounts^>^>^> > "%filename%"

rem wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=4" get deviceid > "%filename%" 2>&1
rem THIS won't work under scheduler ^^

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=4" get deviceid^, freespace^, size') do (
  set "drive=%%d"
  set "free=%%e"
  set "size=%%f"
  if "!drive!" NEQ "" (
    set "drive=!drive:~0,2!"
    if defined size (
      echo drive_!drive! ok !size! !size! !free! 1 >> "%filename%"
    )
  )
)
```

I noticed that if the scheduler runs this script `wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=4" get deviceid` gives `No Instance(s) Available.`
Scheduler is set to run as `abba` user I changed anything in there

Please help me to make this script work (triggered from task scheduler)

Comment: `"drivetype=4"` is Network Drive (4). I think user's profile is not loaded while running scheduled task. So the network drive is not mapped, it doesn't exist. You have to make scheduled task interacts with user: set `non-hidden` & `Run  only when user is loffed on`